# jQuery Maintain aspect ratio of image in an image container; all images in container placed in a single row

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I am providing a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2u6kfygs/) for better explanation

- The 5 rows must be equal height, in spite of the number of images in the row
- I am looking for a container to hold the images and all the image containers must be equal width and height.
- Now what I have is one container holding all the images in row, what  I am looking for is: every image should be in a container and that
  container should be in a row container. And the row length should depend on number of images in it.

```
  <p>topa</p>

    <div id="container2">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/250" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
         <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/250" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
         <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/250" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
         <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/250" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
    </div>
    <p>topb</p>
    <div id="container2">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/250" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
         <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />

    </div>
    <p>topc</p>
    <div id="container2">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/250" />


    </div>
    <p>topd</p>
    <div id="container2">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/250" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />


    </div>
    <p>tope</p>
    <div id="container2">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />
         <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/250" />


    </div>

    <div style="width:598px;text-align:center;border:1px solid #000;margin:10px;">600px</div>

#container2{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding:2px;
}
#container2 img{float:left;}

var container_width = $('#container2').width();
var container_width_temp = 0.0; // must be float!
var container_height = 100.0; // random initial container heigth for calculations

$('#container2 img').each(function(){
    var newwidth = (this.width / this.height) * container_height;
    this.width = newwidth;
    $(this).data('width', newwidth); 
    container_width_temp += newwidth;
});

$('#container2 img').each(function(){
    this.width = $(this).data('width') * (container_width / container_width_temp);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2u6kfygs/)

Comment: What exactly then is the part what you need help with? If you can already tell what your target structure is then why are you not doing that here? I.e. putting each image in a container and all of those in a bigger container.

Comment: i tried few things , but nothing worked , i have posted the last workable code